# How can I add different contents in today extension?

Tags: ios, today-extension

How should I add different contents in Today extension?
(just like native weather).

for example: Above view is UITableview and bottom view is webview

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust your xib of today extension and design what ever you need.

> Note: today extension is only for limited features of application.
>
> Don’t force your entire application features to today extension